# Не изменяется свойство display в выпадающем меню

Tags: html, css, css3

Добрый день. Создаю меню, которое при нажатии на кнопку `#btn-menu` должно развернуться. Изначально меню имеет горизонтальное расположение, но при уменьшении ширины принимает вертикальное и получает `display:none`, а кнопка, которая должна раскрывать меню `display:flex`.

Ни `active` ни `hover` на `#btn-menu` не возвращают `#nav{display:flex}`:

```css
#btn-menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

#btn-menu:active #nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

#nav {
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

#nav>li {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: inherit;
  flex-basis: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn-menu">menu</div>
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не верно заданы селекторы. Вы пишете `#btn-menu:active #nav` - это значит, что `#nav` находится внутри `#btn-menu`. Вам нужно использовать знак `+`, чтобы показать что они следуют друг за другом:

```css
#btn-menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

#btn-menu:active + #nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

#nav {
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

#nav>li {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: inherit;
  flex-basis: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn-menu">menu</div>
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
#btn-menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

#nav {
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

#nav > li {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: inherit;
  flex-basis: inherit;
}

div#btn-menu:hover + #nav {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn-menu">menu</div>
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```